# web.py db.insert() doesn't work

Tags: sql, insert, web.py

I use db.insert() to insert data to database, the code is something like this,

```
db.insert('categories', name=cate_name, description=desc, _test=True)
```

but it doesn't work, the data can't not be found in table 'categories' after the code is execute, and no exceptions by the way.
Anybody know why this happened?

Comment: the _test variable lets you see the SQL produced by the statement.

Comment: it doesn't, I get it now. The _test variable just lets you see the SQL but does not execute it. Thank you!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Consider making your reply an answer so that the question author can accept it. This way, contributors looking for unanswered questions won't mistake this one for an unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

`_Test` variable stands for debug purposes.

It lets you get SQL statement **instead of** executing one.

It means that your command

```
result = db.insert('categories', name=cate_name, description=desc, _test=True)
```

will not execute anything on your DB. It will only return a string:

```
"INSERT INTO categories (name, description) VALUES ('cate_name value', 'desc value')"
```

If you want to make a real query, you need to remove it:

```
db.insert('categories', name=cate_name, description=desc)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove `_test=True` or set `_test=False`